# Show only positive numbers in an array

Tags: c

```
main()
{
    int i,j,n,a[10][10],b[10];
    printf("Intr. n=");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%i",&a[i][j]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%5i",a[i][j]);}
    printf("\npozitive b:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if(a[i][j] >= 0)
        {
            printf("%d  ", b[i]);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

I have this code right here that creates a table and i wanted to create a separate one only with the positive numbers of the first one

when i enter like the values 3 and 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 I get random numbers like 8 40 18421

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Although your compiler might not care, it should be, minimally, `int main()`.

Comment: Tip: Declare iterator variables inside the loop itself, it keeps them scoped: `for (int i = 0; ...)`

Comment: when i enter like the values 3 and 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 i get like 8 40 18421 some random nubmers

Comment: "Random numbers" is usually a sign you're using *uninitialized values* and have undefined behaviour. You really should size these arrays in terms of `n` instead of assuming "10 will be fine!"

Comment: You never assigned anything to `b`, why do you expect to see reasonable output?

Comment: yeah but i used 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 it should had worked anyway

Comment: Those are in `a`, but you're printing `b`. I don't understand why you don't get it.

Comment: because i have to print them on another table

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is copy all the positive numbers into `b`, and then loop through `b` to print them?

Comment: YES but how do i do that

Comment: someone is wrong with this right         if(a[i][j] >= 0)
        {
            printf("%d  ", b[i]);
        }?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `#include<stdio.h>` so scanf and printf can work i edit your code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Intr. n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n][n],b[n*n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    int p=0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        if(a[i][j] >= 0){
            b[p++]=a[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    printf("\npositive b:");
    for(i =0;i<p;i++)
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 i get the same

Comment: @Johncollins you tried to display value from array b[10] but you never stored any thing in it that why its not working its is giving you any random value `printf("%d  ", b[i]);`

Comment: yeah but the point is to display only the pozitive values on the b table

Comment: i will edit it once or your input from 1 to 9 ok

Comment: @Johncollins positive value are getting stored in b[10] now